# Why can't I upload a portfolio to Yahoo Finance?

Tags: upload, yahoo

I used to be able to upload a new portfolio to Yahoo Finance by, while logged in, going to

- https://finance.yahoo.com/portfolios

clicking "Import", and submitting a CSV file. But when I do that now, I get the error message:

> There was some error while importing your portfolio. Please Try Again.

I never found any documentation of the structure of CSV file it requires, but the structure that I found worked in the past was:

```
Symbol,Trade Date,Quantity,Purchase Price,Commission
AAPL,2024 02 04,100,200,0
MSFT,2024 02 04,100,400,0
GOOG,2024 02 04,100,150,0
```

I submitted a test file with those contents and the filename "yahootest.csv" and got the above error message.

I signed up for a subscription for Yahoo Support for about $5 a month and submitted this issue. I got a series of responses that were completely useless, and I cancelled the subscription.

I can't be the only person who is experiencing this new inability to upload a portfolio. I'm surprised that searching neither Google nor Stack Exchange brings up anything useful about that error message.

Has uploading portfolios been disabled, or am I doing something wrong?

It would be great if some other people would try uploading that file and see if you get the same error. Or better yet if you find a way to upload those data successfully.

Comment: Website and Web services are off topic here and except insofar as the problem is in your browser or computer. I'm not sure if this is on topic at [webapps.se] but I suspect only Yahoo support can really know.